# CakePHP without htaccess and mod_rewrite - how to overwrite WEB URL PATH

Tags: php, cakephp

So I installed CakePHP on a IIS box and followed the steps of uncommenting the appropriate lines in core.php to make my URLs work as index.php/controllername/methodname/

My only problem now is that all the convenience functions such as $html->css, $html->link, etc. are pointing to some wacky paths. If I am viewing index.php/pages/home doing $html->link('Test', '/pages/test') produces a link to index.php/pages/pages/test/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my plugin paths and I posted a [ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/500-plugin-css-directories-bug#ticket-500-4). 
Try to insert `../../` at the beginning of the path.

```
$html->css('../../your_style_sheet');
```

For the links use this syntax:

```
$html->link('Test', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'test'));
```

Comment: use DS: $html->css('..' . DS . '..' . DS . 'your_style_sheet');